# How to highlight character by character in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

Just wondering if there is a way to highlight a sentence but not have it jump to enclose whole words.

re-wording just incase:

If you try and highlight something from the middle of a word it will automatically highlight that entire word, but what if i just want it to highlight character by character... as it should IMO. I am looking for something similar to holding the control or shift key as you highlight but for what i stated above.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already indicated, `Shift` is your friend.

However, it isn't just about holding down shift.

If you start selecting from the middle of a word, and then press `Shift` down before you move the cursor, it will select from the point you clicked, but then encompass words as you select further into the text.

What you do is select slightly more than what you need, then select less, ie. back up a bit. This will deselect the whole words and select only the text you wanted.

It takes a bit of practice to get the technique right, but if you select more than what you need, while holding down shift, then selecting less, you should get what you want.

Without shift, notice that it selects the whole first word no matter what:

[image: without shift]

With shift, notice that it deselects the whole word and selects only what I want:

[image: with shift]

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Enable Caret Browsing > Restart IE

F7 will also toggle Caret Browsing.

Now you can click anywhere in any paragraph, and holding SHIFT, navigate right, left, up or down to make a selection.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight a bit of it then hold Shift and press the arrow keys in the direction you're highlighting.